# need help with solid color layer on photoshop

Tags: color

[image]

I'm trying to change the color of my typeface on photoshop so i selected

solid color layer and set the blend mode to color but the color of the

typeface didn't change as the color i selected but only the outline of typeface.

how do i change the color of the typeface clearly with the solid color just like the picture below? (done by someone else)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess: You want solid edges, but fading colors. Blurring has also faded the edges, which you didnt want.

A solution: Have non-blurred copies of your shapes and use them as clipping masks or make with them selections for deleting the extra blurred area:

[image]

Here 1 and 2 are intermediate phases, only 3 (=blurred and clipped) is the result. How to do it:

- Have your shape in a layer with no background
- Duplicate your shape layer
- Blur the copy
- Goto the shape layer and select with the Magic Wand the transparent exterior of the shape
- Goto the blurred layer and press DEL
- Hide the non-blurred shape layer

Now you are ready to add the coloring layer, if the original color wasn't ok.

*The guessing continues*: The solid parts of your shapes have not taken the color, they stay black.

A solution: Turn them to grey with levels or curves. Grey takes color, black and white do not.

Here a coloring layer is added as you already have tried. Only the lower half of the shapes are affected. The solid black stays black.

[image]

If the blurring is only light, there's also no effect in the middle of the shapes. That can be fixed by turning black to grey with the levels or curves tool. Here's an adjustmet layer for that is added:

[image]